# Is there an MVC function that converts "item[0]" to "item_0_"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm using MVC3 with Razor and I've noticed that Html helper functions generate html tags that have their names attributes like I asked them to, but have specific format for id attribute. If I try to generate a checkbox and pass "item[0]" as a name parameter, I'll get a checkbox with "item[0]" as name but "item_0_" for id.

I'm guessing there's a good reason for that, and I'm guessing that there's a function that does this string to string conversion? Do you know which function does that? I need to do this type of conversion in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
GetFullHtmlFieldId
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.templateinfo.getfullhtmlfieldid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because a `[` is not valid in an html id. Such a funciton would be very easy to write yourself though:

```
public string SanitizeID(string dirtyID)
{
     return dirtyID
         .Replace("[", "_")
         .Replace("]", "_")
         .Replace(".", "_");

     // add any other replace as needed
}
```

**EDIT**
This answer might point you in the right direction: [Preventing ASP.NET MVC from Replacing period with underscore in Html Helper IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581998/preventing-asp-net-mvc-from-replacing-period-with-underscore-in-html-helper-ids/582022#582022)

**EDIT 2**
[This post of Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) appears to hint that such behaviour is defined in the DefaultModelBinder.cs class. I cannot check the ASP.NET MVC sources now, but you might want to take a look there...

Comment: That's what I did, but I's rather use the system function, since I'm not sure which other replacements I need to do.

Comment: @77v - I've added a link to an answer that might get you closer to what you want... although not completely there, I'll admit...

Answer (score 0):

This may be in the Control class in asp.net - have a look there, not MVC

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the MSDN page for [Control.ID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx):

> Note
>   Only combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error.

So it looks like you should be ok using something like:

```
string id = ...;
id = Regex.Replace(id, @"\W", "_");
```

But yes it would be nice to find a system method.