# Javascript not firing when changing HTMLDropDownListFor value

Tags: javascript, razor

I have this dropdown list.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Puppies, Model.Puppy.PuppyList, new { @class = "dashboard-control",     placeholder = "Select Puppy" })
```

Markup:

```
<select class="dashboard-control" data-val="true" id="Puppies" name="Puppies" placeholder="Select Puppy"><option value="2">Lab</option>
```

Poodle

The name and id of this dropdown is Puppies, verified in Inspector.

I have this javascript in my View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Puppies").on("change", function() {

            var selected = $(this).val();
            $("#description").html("You selected: " + selected);

        })
    });
</script>
```

When I place a break in the Chrome Sources window on the function, it only stops there on page load.   I don't see any obvious problems.  According to the documentation I read for .on, it should fire when the value is changed.  I even tabbed out of the combo to see if that was when it would fire.   What am I missing?

Comment: what is the markup generated by the first snippet?

Comment: I've added the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is working now.  In my attempt to obfuscate the model and id of the drop down, I manually typed the id #Animals.Puppies' in the demo code.   Well, apparently HTML helpers, such as the one I was using @Html.DropDownListFor, change periods to underscores automatically in the id.  Since I was placing a period in the function when referencing the ID, naturally it never fired on change of the drop down.   There is a discussion about this and the code that does this, in this question [Preventing ASP.NET MVC from Replacing period with underscore in Html Helper IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581998/preventing-asp-net-mvc-from-replacing-period-with-underscore-in-html-helper-ids)

When I referenced the id of the dropdown correctly with the underscore, not a period, the script worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing where there's anything wrong with your code. this is essentially the same thing, and I've tested both ways.

## edit

Now that you've made clearer the `id` you're using, you should escape the period in the jquery selector so that it doesn't mistake it for a class. code tested, works.

```
$(function() {
    $('#Animals\\.Puppies').on("change", function() {
        var selected = $(this).children(':selected').text();
        $("#description").html("You selected: " + selected);
     
    }).change();
});
```

Comment: Same results.  It breaks on load, but not when I change the dropdown.  Is it illegal to have a period in my name/id?   I have replaced it with Puppies in this example, but in my code its similar to Animals.Puppies.

Comment: as in the `id` of the html element? that's what has the id of 'Animals.Puppies'?

Comment: yes, I think i have found the answer to that question here (it does seem legal)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html  which leaves me still scratching my head.

Comment: yeah, I've never tried to use `.` in an id, but since jquery takes that to mean a class, you should try escaping it. i.e. `$('#Animals\\.Puppies')`

Comment: No luck.   Even after escaping it.   Does the fact it breaks on load indicate it's valid js and I haven't goofed something up like a } or )?

Comment: that seems most likely, yeah, that it's something else going on. I broke it for a moment when testing the id with a period, which the escaping fixed. **what do mean by breaks on load, exactly?**

Comment: by break on load I mean it stops at the break point i place in the function when the page loads initially.

Comment: oh, ok... well, that's a good thing, right? Have you learned anything helpful through debugging your code like this/

Comment: No, because the on change doesn't fire on page load.  It should be firing when I select a new value in the dropdown.

Comment: keep your breakpoint where it is -- or thereabout -- add the above changes to handler.

Comment: No, still not firing.  I added your edits and it still only stops on my breakpoint on initial page load.   I have other js that runs on other views in my project and I have added this script the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("body").on("change", "#Puppies", function() 
{
    var selected = $(this).find(":selected").val();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried it outside $(document).ready(function() {..} or $(function(){ ... })?

Comment: So what happens if you add <script> $("body").on("change","#Puppies", function(){...}); </script> within the body tag? Just ouf interest.

Comment: It still wont fire. I removed the $(document) and $(function).