# How to get a reference to id="xxx.yyy" in CSS?

Tags: css

In the HTML code there is a div like:

```
<div id="xxx.yyy">...</div>
```

I want to specify the style in a css file. How can I get a reference to this div? The following does not seem to work:

```
#xxx.yyy {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: because that's calling the class yyy as a companion to the id xxx. Like <div id="xxx" class="yyy">. Also, this is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also do something like this...

```
​div[id="xxx.yyy"] {
    /* your styles here */
}​​​​​​
```

The spec says it all: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/mjGzQ/

Answer (score 8):

```css
#xxx\.yyy {

}
```

Should do the trick. No harm done in using dots in CSS id names

Comment: No harm? Having to escape them sucks, especially when there are separators like `_` and `-` which work fine.

Comment: Well, one can simply not use dots or underline or hyphen. Some choices come with a price and I find that a single \ does not hurt anyone

Comment: check out my answer... you don't *have* to escape to select: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12700730/196921

Comment: Well, it's a standard procedure. Which browser are you using to test your code? Are you sure you were not viewing a cached page?