# Programmably click li img in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to click one of my LI thumbnails. The HTML code for this is:

```
<ul id="thumbImgs" class="list" style="height: 250px;">
   <li id="04_BOARDWALK_VIEW.jpg" data-wh="1000|700|testing 3" class="item">
      <img src="cms/img/uploaded/04_BOARDWALK_VIEW_tmb.jpg" width="120" height="120" class="imgStyle" style="opacity: 0.5;">
   </li>
   etc etc....
</ul>
```

I've already tried:

```
$('#04_BOARDWALK_VIEW.jpg').click();

$("#thumbImgs li #04_BOARDWALK_VIEW.jpg").click();

$("#thumbImgs li 04_BOARDWALK_VIEW.jpg").click();
```

But that does not seem to work. What would i be missing?

Comment: Do you want to trigger a click on the image, or the `li`? Your question title says 'li img' but you appear to be trying to select the ID of the `li`.

Comment: Please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you have is the period in your id.  That is generally poor practice, but can be overcome in jQuery if you escape the period in the selector.  Do it like this:

```
$("#04_BOARDWALK_VIEW\\.jpg").click();
```

Note the need for double backslash as `\` is an escapes charater in javascript, so you need one backslash to actually escape the real backslash which is needed by jQuery to escape the period.  Again, best practice would have you not using the periods in the id's at all.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! That did the trick. Knew it had to be something simply i was just overlooking.

Answer (score 7):

`.` is a special character and therefore needs to be escaped.

```
$('#04_BOARDWALK_VIEW\\.jpg')
```

Though I also wonder how you were able to add a click handler to the image without doing this.

Your original selector `#04_BOARDWALK_VIEW.jpg` would get you an element with an `id` of `#04_BOARDWALK_VIEW` and a **class** of `jpg`.

Comment: Don't you need two slashes?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yup, fixed that nearly immediately but I guess you got in before I did.

Comment: Thanks for your comment as well, James!