# Jquery .text() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an anchor tag like this:

```
<a id="1_18_shazin@mycompany.com" class="big-link" href="">4</a>
```

Now I am trying to replace the text with the following code

```
a = 1;
b = 18;
c = "shazin@mycompany.com";
var tempId = "#"+a+"_"+b+"_"+c;
$(tempId).text("some text");
```

Thiis never works. I tried .html(), .append(). Looks like it never finds the ID. 
But it works if I call the event by class name.

```
$(".big-link").text("some text");
```

Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you do a http://jsfiddle.net for us?

Comment: First problem I see is the use of `@` in your ID and having it begin with a digit. Please see this SO answer for details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: The snippet works fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: Problem is the `@` and `.` characters in the `id`. Check this SO answer for the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: http://jsbin.com/aqoxij/1 check this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are constructing your ID values. Issues are

1. Starting with a digit
2. Use of @
3. Use of .

I removed those and jquery text() was working fine for me. Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kDnmu/

HTML

```
<a id="A_1_18_shazin_mycompany-com" class="big-link" href="">4</a>
```

Jquery

```
a = 1;
b = 18;
c = "shazin_mycompany-com";
var tempId = "#A_"+a+"_"+b+"_"+c;
$(tempId).text("some text");
```

For details on what is a valid id check this SO answer: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

**EDIT:** If you are constructing these IDs dynamically, consider escaping them with some logic of your own.

Comment: @shazinltc its not necessary you can see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/LPuTr/

```
a = 1;
b = 18;
c = "shazin@mycompany.com";
aaa = a+'_'+b+'_'+c;

$('a[id="'+aaa+'"]').text("some text");
```

for more info for `ids` in `html 5` see this: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: Excellent example, it is far simpler this way, but you need a browser that supports html5.

Comment: @Floradu88 Its not necessary though you can test it on `ie7` or `ie8` will work absolutely fine.

Comment: you are right, this needed to be the *marked* answer +1 from me for this

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dot(.) and `@` characters with `\\`. try this

```
$("#1_18_shazin\\@mycompany\\.com").text("some text");
```

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/HLtz9/10/

Comment: For my curiosity, How does the use of the \\ help avoid the ID validity requirements ?

Comment: hey @ryadavilli, i really dont know in details, just got a similar problem once and learnt this by googling.

Comment: Found some explanation here : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and some details here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Answer (score 1):

You have illegal characters in your id, also an id cannot begin with a digit

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you have to loose period . and alpha @ and then it works!

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

I understand why alpha, but I have no clue for period :/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is working JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/zpTaG/)

Problem is you are using `@` and `.` in your id

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

`@` is not legal for ID while `.` and `:` is allowed but one should avoid it because:

> For example, an ID could be labelled "a.b:c" and referenced in the
>   style sheet as #a.b:c but as well as being the id for the element, it
>   could mean id "a", class "b", pseudo-selector "c"

.