# jQuery id selector not working when have . in ID

Tags: php, jquery

My html code is as below.

```
<div id="chatbox_dipesh.parmar" class="chatbox">
  //html markup which is validated
</div>
```

in above code `dipesh.parmar` div added dynamically.

And i am accessing it using following code.

```
$("#chatbox_"+chatboxtitle).show();
```

where `chatboxtitle` is `dipesh.parmar` but its not selecting div.

Does `.` is not a valid for ID.?

My jQuery is loaded and its not conflicting with other library and also wrapped it into `$(function(){  })`.

Thanks.

Comment: Escape the dot.

See this:
[Direction][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: `$("#chatbox_dipesh.parmar")` will look for an element having `id` as `chatbox_dipesh` and `class` as `parmar`.

Comment: @Rob so quick with perfect solution.

Comment: Does . is not a valid for ID.? : YES
to avoid this use \\ and make it work :)

Comment: @Rob don't worry you will be rewarded dude...Thanx so much..wait for 10 min bro

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Escape the dot.

See this:
[Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

Comment: there you go...bingo..

Comment: @Rob - Please don't go around SO editing the code whitespace. It's not the done thing. You need to make substantive edits. Unless the code readability is significantly improved it should be left alone.