# jQuery: How do I identify an element whose ID contains a dot?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#edit-name").change(function() {
    $("#Membership_UserName").val($(this).val());
  });
  $("#edit-pass-pass1").change(function() {
    $("#Membership_PassWord").val($(this).val());
  });
  $("#edit-pass-pass2").change(function() {
    $("#.Verify_Password").val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Everything works fine, *except* for updating the value of the element whose ID is `.Verify_Password`. The reason seems pretty apparent to me (that jQuery is getting confused after seeing `#` and `.` right next to each other) but maybe that's wrong...

Regardless, the ID can't be changed because it's being sent to a remote endpoint and it needs to match on that end.

So my question is: is there a way to tell jQuery that `.Verify_Password` is an ID (and not a class)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361015/jquery-id-selector-not-working-when-have-in-id

Comment: You could just use `document.getElementById()` and wrap that in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do this by escape it.

```
$('#\\.Verify_Password');
```

**OR**

```
$("[id='.Verify_Password']")
```

Comment: I doubt that the latter will be optimised by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("#\\.Verify_Password").val($(this).val());` 
or read up on [jQuery selector value escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739695/jquery-selector-value-escaping)

Answer (score 1):

You should double escape it

```
 $("#\\.Verify_Password").val($(this).val());
```

Check this jQuery [doc](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) for more info, Few examples -

```
// Does not work
$("#some:id")

// Works!
$("#some\\:id")

// Does not work
$("#some.id")

// Works!
$("#some\\.id")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indicate a selector with `#` then it will be an `ID` or if you indicate a selector witn `.` then it will be an `CLASS`.

If you didnt know whether it is an id or class then try like

```
$("#edit-pass-pass2").change(function() {
    $("#\\.Verify_Password").val($(this).val());
});
```