# Div id containing the character "." is not being selected by jquery

Tags: jquery

I have divs with ids as below:

```
<div id="text.header" class="countDiv"></div>
<div id="text.content" class="countDiv"></div> etc
```

I have two arrays. In the first i have, array1 = [1,2] and in the other I store the ids of all the divs using the following snippet

```
$(".countDiv").each(function(i){
    array2[i] = $(this).attr("id");
}
```

then I use `.html()` to write the value of `i` into the id of the div by using:

```
for(var myCount = 0; myCount < array1.length; myCount++){
    $("#" + array2[i]).html(array1[i]);
}
```

The problem is that for all cases its fine, but when i use `.` in between the ids, the code doesn't work. No error is showed on the console.

eg: when i use , ,  it works well, but when i use , the page is blank. The code doesn't work.

Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Think about what `$("#test.header")` will select, considering `.` usually precedes a classname.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at what your resulting selector string will look like, you'll see the problems that this line causes:

```
$("#"+array2[i])
```

Let's say the id is `text.header`. Look at what the resulting selector string becomes:

```
$('#text.header')
```

This selector will match an element with an id of `text` and a class of `header`. That's not what you want. The jQuery solution would be to escape the dot, but a better way would be to just use the native DOM method and wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
$(document.getElementById(array2[i]))
```

I didn't see this approach listed in the duplicate question, so I might as well post it here.

Comment: **+1** for combining jQuery with DOM method `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned `myCount` and didn't use it.
Also jquery creates problem while using `.` in `id` so use `javascript` here for
`selecting id`

```
var array2=new Array();
var array1 = [1,2];
$(".countDiv").each(function(){
   array2.push($(this).attr("id"));
});

for(i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    document.getElementById(array2[i]).innerHTML=(array1[i]);
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/gEScc/1/

Comment: life saver!!!thanks dude...worked.. Dhanyawaad!

Answer (score 0):

The `.` represents a class selector in jQuery (and CSS). Consider escaping it to `\.`

```
$("#" + array2[i].replace(".", "\\."))...
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslash as well: `\\.`

Comment: Well, of course. See edit

Answer (score -1):

.Yes.

'.' is the class path separator in CSS and therefore and obviously can not be used in class names.

Thats by design (CSS).

Comment: OP is using it in an id attribute, which is fine.

Comment: Yes. But jQuery recognises it as a class name separator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot