# jQuery select ID containing dot

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some nodes which may occasionally contain a dot in their ID attribute,

Example: `<div id="site_someSite.com"></div>`

Then I need to select this element ( I'm using jQuery ) and I do this:

`variable = $('#site_'+user);` user being `'someSite.com'`

And I get nothing in the variable. I suppose this is due to the dot in the name which jQuery is accepting as a class. Anyone has any idea how I can work around this without not-using a dot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select html nodes by ID with jquery when the id contains a dot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need to do is select by the `id`, then you can use `document.getElementById`:

```
var div = document.getElementById('site_'+user);
```

Note that this will obviously give a native DOM element. If you need a jQuery selection, you can wrap this in the jQuery constructor:

```
var div = $(document.getElementById('site_'+user));
```

This has the additional advantage of being faster! Obviously it won't work if you have anything else in your selector.

Answer (score 7):

You can use it but  escape it by backslashes,like `$('#example\\.afterdottext');`

[As per docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Answer (score 6):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RwgAU/)**

Use attribute selectors<sup>1</sup>:

```
var site = 'someSite.com';
var variable = $('[id="site_' + site + '"]');

// do something
variable.css('background', 'yellow');
```

---

References:

- <sup>1</sup> [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 5):

You can do this -

```
variable = $('#site_'+user.replace(/\./g,'\\.'));
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/wdJka/2/

Comment: Doesn't seem to pick that up either :/