# Alert on inputting a particular Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an error/alert message if the user's input a particular values(% or *). If the user enter just % or * and hit 'submit' then an alert or message should say "This is not allowed". However, SM%TH or *MITH should be allowed.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.3." id="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.3." value="" class="forminfree">
<input type="submit" name="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.7." id="ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.7." value="Search" class="formsubfree" style="width:100px" onclick="searchCheck()">
```

SCRIPT

```
function searchCheck(){
}
```

As always your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: search for regex and see what can be done with it

Comment: Quite the function you got there!

Comment: You shouldnt use dot in your id name, it is just complicating thing in the query selector and add backslashs.

Comment: What is this? fill in the code? Nice...

Comment: ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.3. is not a valid ID. You can't just use any character that looks nice in a ID or a class. What you're using here, used in a selector, means all tags "ANSWER" with the classes "TTQ", "MENSYS", "3", "", which would obviously lead to errors.

Comment: @Virus721  Its valid. check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17810857/438624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be having issues while accessing the ID which is having a dot(.). Inorder to avoid that you must use `$('#ANSWER\\.TTQ\\.MENSYS\\.3\\.')` this way.

```
  function searchCheck(){
         var answer = $.trim($('#ANSWER\\.TTQ\\.MENSYS\\.3\\.').val());
         if(answer == '*' || answer == '%') alert('this is not allowed');
    }
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/Kk8GC/

Comment: Hi! VeeKayBee..I had this yesterday without the $('#ANSWER\\.TTQ\\.MENSYS\\.3\\.'). Thank you. Also, after clicking on the alert the form gets submitted. return false does not stop it.

Comment: @19eggs Great !!!. Happy that you got a solution. I am sorry that I saw your comment now only and happy that you fixed by yourself. :)

Comment: @19eggs refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot But I think some browsers it may not work. So better to use underscores(_) instead of dots(.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function searchCheck(){
     var answer = $.trim($(this).find('input[type=text]').val());
     if(answer == '*' || answer == '%') alert('this is not allowed');
}
```

Comment: +1 for the trim. Edited my answer to include it after I saw you using it.

Comment: Hi! Karl-Andre Gagnon,
I am afraid it did not work. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First fetch the value. With jQuery:

```
var str = $("#ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.3.").val();
```

<strike>With KY</strike> Without jQuery:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("ANSWER.TTQ.MENSYS.3.");
var str = elem.value;
```

Now you just check it out:

```
str = str.trim();
if (str == "*" || str == "%") {
    alert("This is not allowed. Get off my system!");
}
```

Comment: Hi! Renan, I have not tried your code, but I am sure it would work as it is similar to VeeKayBee's reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Crawl over the string, check for preceeding * or % and stop with follow up of ** or %* but not %%.

```
function searchCheck(){

var pos=0;
var error=false;
var prior=false;

while(pos<your_string.length && !error){
  if(prior){
    if(your_string.charAt(pos) == '*'){
      error = true;
    } else if(your_string.charAt(pos) != '%') prior = false;
  } else { 
    if(your_string.charAt(pos) == '%' || your_string.charAt(pos) == '*')
      prior = true;   
  }
  pos++;
}
if(error || (your_string.length==1 && prior)){
    alert("not allowed");
}

}
```

Comment: Hi! Lemmy,  I have decided to use VeeKayBee's answer as it is shorter. But thank you for taking your time and replying.