# how to print text box value which id having dot(.)s

Tags: jquery

I want to print the text box value which id having dot(.)s.

Ex:

```
<input type="text" id="abc.xyz" value="Hiii"/>
```

How to print this value using jquery.

Comment: You need to Escape the dot.

[See Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: `$("#abc\\.xyz").val();`

Comment: this id will generate automatically...

Answer (score 1):

You need to Escape the dot.

```
$('#abc\\.xyz').val();
```

[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

You can also do this using below,

```
$("input[id='abc.xyz']")
```

Answer (score 0):

use `\\` to escape `.` operator  since it is a class selector in jquery,

try this..

```
$("#abc\\.xyz").val();
```

Comment: What was wrong with this ? Who did the -1 ? +1 to balance the universe :)

Comment: @Jashwant, thanks .... downvoter..are you serious ???  can u please explain why ??