# How to read selected value of dropdown in ASP.net MVC using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple form with two field `1. Amount` and `2. Creditcard type` (Dropdown). Functionality wise dropdown is working fine and whatever I select I am able to get that in my backend code. But somehow I am not able to access the selected value of dropdown using JQuery. Kindly guide me. Below is code snippet

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBox(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "Amount", Model.Amount,
                new { @class = "form-control required" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreditDetails.CreditCard, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 required" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCard", SimUtils.PayTypesSelect,
                    new { @class = "form-control", id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails.CreditCard" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Some of my attempts to get the value or the text of dropdown. I always get output as `undefined`.

```
 var x = $('#CreditDetails.CreditCard :selected').val();
        var t = $('#CreditDetails.CreditCard').val();
        var f = $('#@(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCard") option:selected').val();
        $("#SelectedCountryId option:selected").text()
            var d = $('#CreditDetails.CreditCard option:selected').text();
            var s = $('#@(Model.ModelPropertyPrefixName + "CreditDetails.CreditCard") option:selected').text();
```

I am successfully able to get the amount value entered by the user

```
var amountText = $('#@(Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "Amount")').val() // WORKS FINE
```

Generated Code in Front End:

```
    <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Card Type must be a number." data-val-required="The Card Type field is required." id="CreditDetails.CreditCard" name="CreditDetails.CreditCard"><option selected="selected" value="-6">Amex</option>
    <option value="-4">Discover</option>
    <option value="-3">Master Card</option>
    <option value="1">test</option>
    <option value="-5">Visa</option>
    </select>


<div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control required" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Amount must be a number." id="Amount" name="Amount" type="text" value="">
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Amount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
```

I know the dropdown and the amount code looks dirty but bear with me here. Everything is working fine. I just want to access the dropdown value before the form gets submitted. But I don't know why I am not able to do so.

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in your selector using `\\.`

Comment: `id="CreditDetails.CreditCard` is not a valid - the dot will act as a class selector. Remove your `new { id = Model.ModelPropertyPrefix + "CreditDetails.CreditCard" }` and let the `HtmlHelper` generate the correct `id` attribute (which will replace the `.` with an `_` (underscore)). And what in the world is `Model.ModelPropertyPrefix`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: You have solved my alot of SO questions/issues. I am working with extra dirty old code. I am just a fresher and have been told to fix issues and stuffs. Actually dropdown works as expected. I mean I am able to capture the correct value in the backend. I know you are right. But is there any way to fix this and not change the existing convention. P.S: this code is not written by me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Yes, I remember it now - you really need to abandon that 'prefix' nonsense :) You can always just give it your own `id` - `new { id="xxx" }` and use `$('#xxx').val()` or use the default which will be `$('#CreditDetails_CreditCard').val()`

Comment: paul and stehen : Thank You so so much. I am able to get the value now by using escape sequence. @Stephen: I will definitely pay heed to your advice and will hope that it does not create any cascading effect. P.S: I have added the "front end generated code" so that I don't get negative vote from you.  :D

Comment: Downvote? You have clearly explained the problem and provided the code to be able to reproduce and identify the issue :)