# How do I get an form selected value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How should I get an form input selected value using jQuery

```
<form:select path="amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat" id="amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat" cssClass="state">
  <option value="">선택</option>
  <form:options name="monit" items="${apps}" itemValue="subCd" itemLabel="subCdNm" />
</form:select> 
<img src="<c:url value='/resources/img/read.png'/>" class="read" id="appStatSearch"></td>
```

Comment: use `:selected` selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need get the `.val()` of the `amtAppCollInfoVO_mkType` select input:

```
var some_var = $('#amtAppCollInfoVO_mkType').val();
```

For pure Javascript just switch `.val()` to `.value`

Note that your current option does not have a value.

Note that since you have the `.` in your id you have to add double `\` to your Javascript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#amtAppMonitResltVO\\.monitStat').on('click', function() {
            var moniStat = $('#amtAppMonitResltVO\\.monitStat').val();

            console.log(moniStat);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Credit goes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605835/1527252) for this answer.

Comment: Right, have you attempted to add a `value` to your option? The parameter is empty. You could also try something like `$('select[id= amtAppCollInfoVO_mkType]').val()` if it is still returns null

Comment: What exactly are you seeing? Can you give the console error report?

Comment: I tried $("#amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat").val() and It gives undefined

Comment: Are you just doing that on load? First, remove that period between the fields in the `ID`. Then Try to add a function and wait for a `change` on the value of your select: `<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#amtAppMonitResltVO').on('change', function() {
            
            var some = $("#amtAppMonitResltVO").val()
            console.log(some);
        })
    })

</script>`

Comment: Samuel U missed .monitStat ? path="amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat" I tried it in detail.js  console.log('selected value: ',$("#amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat").val()); it gives undefined

Comment: is itemValue just same as value?

Comment: I meant to leave `.monitStat` out, it is the reason you are getting the error man. @minmoica

Comment: it gives undefined without .monitStat and also there are many ohter form with amtAppMonitResultVO like amtAppMonitResltVO.monitStat,amtAppMonitResltVO.paymMethd in same jsp page

Comment: @minmoica use (this answer right here)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/605835/1527252]. This should fix your issue by adding double `\\` before the period

Comment: @minmoica I've updated my answer for you to see what I am talking about.

Comment: Samual I gave the seperate Id like amtAppMonitResultVO_monitStat and it work

Answer (score 0):

The one option you have has no value, but if you set a value for it, you could use a selector like the following to get the value of the first selected option.
`$("#amtAppCollInfoVO_mkType option:selected").val()`

If you wanted all the option values in an array you could use the map method.

`var arr = $("#amtAppCollInfoVO_mkType option").map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();`

Comment: it gives undefined