# Using variable in Multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, jquery-selectors, thymeleaf

I use JQuery 1.11 and want to act on all ids beginning with `partitions0.instances0.natures` and ending with `typeCle` like : `id="partitions0.instances0.natures0.typeCle"`. Then I will affect to those, the same value than my selected element. But my problem here is on the selector.

I've tried many things like `​$('[id^='+instanceId'][id$=typesCle]')` with or without double quotes but can't find the right answer by now. The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

All the jquery code :

```
var instanceId = $(this).attr("id");
var natureId = $(this).attr("id");
var valeur = $(this).prop('value');
natureId = natureId.replace("typesCle", "nature").replace(/\./g, '\\\\.');
​​$('[id^='+ natureId +'][id$=typesCle]').each(){
    this.val(valeur);
}
```

I've also replaced the variable by its value to check and I 've the same error message :

```
​$('[id^=partitions0\\.instances0\\.nature][id$=typesCle]').each(){
    console.log(valeur);
    this.val(valeur);
}
```

The html code :

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
       <select th:field="*{partitions[__${rowPartitionStat.index}__].instances[__${rowInstanceStat.index}__].typesCle}" class="form-control modRepInstance">
         <option th:each="typeCle : ${allTypesCle}"
           th:value="${typeCle}" th:text="${typeCle}">...</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably need to escape the `.` in the `instanceId` value so they are not interpreted by Sizzle as class selectors.

Comment: Your current code has a `+` missing and has a single `"` `​$('[id^='+instanceId + '][id$=typesCle]')` - Not sure if this is your actual code or copypasta errors. Also, if you expect a collection of elements `.val()` will only be against the first match and you might need to use a `.each()`

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `.` in IDs, since they're used in selectors to mean that what follows is a class name. While you can escape them, it's inconvenient.

Comment: @Barmar : It's spring/thymeleaf generated id, so I don't think I can change it simply.

Comment: @Fran : what would be your correction, ​​$('[id^='+instanceId+'][id$=typesCle]').val($(this).prop('value'));` does the same error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Comment: @jayjaypg22 You have a syntax error. Your selector is most likely not valid syntax. Have you escaped the periods `.` as `Rory` suggested? e.g: `\\.` Please write out your selector to your console to make sure the selector is valid. e.g: `console.log('[id^='+instanceId+'][id$=typesCle]');` - Please see the answers in this SO question showing ways to work with periods in id selectors [**How to select html nodes by ID with jquery when the id contains a dot?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

Comment: @Fran I've added the html code. It used thymeleaf to interact with my java code. I can't escape the '.' because it's generated code. The `console.log('[id^='+instanceId+'][id$=typesCle]');` returns : `[id^=partitions0.instances0.typesCle][id$=typesCle]
`

Comment: @jayjaypg22 You escape the dot inside the selector not the actual html identifier. Just replace `.` with `\\.` in your `instanceId` and it will work. You can use `.replace()` for that as well.

Comment: @Fran thanks, the escape works but I still have the same error : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`on the line ​`$('[id^=partitions0\\.instances0\\.nature][id$=typesCle]').each(){`. I've updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little to and fro it seems you don't need to escape the dot and just need to surround the selector with an extra pair of double quotes `"`.

Your original code actually had the first double quote in it but in the wrong place and it had the closing quote missing as well as a missing `+`, hence the syntax error.

Overall, the difference from your original code is repositioning of the opening quote, adding the closing quote and adding the second `+`

Org: `​'"[id^='+instanceId'][id$=typesCle]'`
New: `'[id^="'+ instanceId + '"][id$=typesCle]'`

The example below seems to work. Though you still will need to use the `.each()` to iterate through all the matches.

```js
var outerId = 'partitions0.instances0.nature';

$(document).ready(function() {
 var selector = '[id^="' + outerId + '"][id$=typesCle]';
 console.log(selector);
 
 var x = $(selector);
 console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <select id="partitions0.instances0.nature.SomeUniqueValue.typesCle">
         <option value="Option1Value1" text="Option1Value1">Select1Option1Value1</option>
       </select>
  <select id="partitions0.instances0.nature.SomeOtherValue.typesCle">
         <option value="Option1Value1" text="Option1Value1">Select2Option1Value1</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your perseverance!