# inconsistent behaviour in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#a.b') // doesn't work

document.getElementById('a.b') // works

$('[id="a.b"]') // works
```

Can anyone explain why `$('#a.b')` doesn't work.

Comment: `$('#a.b')` selects element with id a and class b.

Comment: Well... i guess that dot means class to jquery...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Read the documentation https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: It's clear. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

Comment: Is `a` is the id and `b` is the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use meta characters in your Id's while using Jquery.

`.` is a meta character and selector see them as regex. You need to escape to make it work. For ex `\\.`

In this case -

```
$('#a\\.b')
```

Javascript `getElementById` also works because, for it, it's just a String.

When you giving as `id="a.b"` it checks for a value and won't get treated as meta character.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery thinks it is a class. So, you write it using escape sequence as -

```
$('#a\\.b')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the escaping operator as follows:

```
$('#a\\.b')
```

jQuery does not allow meta-characters as a literal part of a name, and those must be escaped with two backslashes `\\`.