# How to target input elements by name property that has special characters using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field which is created after looping through a data structure and creating html on the go. It looks like this

```
<input data-role="tagsinput" type="text" name="sales.sales_channel,no_tx" class="form-control" style="font-size:20px;">
```

Now I want to target the element by name. So this is what I do

```
$(`[name=${obj.table}.${key},${value.islow}]`)
```

This creates the identifier like below

```
[name=sales.sales_channel,no_tx]
```

But I get this error

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=sales.sales_channel,no_tx]
```

So I figured that jquery doesn't understand special characters and those special characters has to be escaped as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/605835/5550284

So I did something like this

```
$(`[name=${obj.table}\\.${key}\\,${value.islow}]`)
```

But this doesn't work either. So how do I target the element by name containing special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the issue of the special characters in the `name`, wrap the value in double quotes:

```
$(`[name="${obj.table}.${key},${value.islow}"]`)
```