# Jquery selector not working when element contains dot in tag name

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jquery-selectors

I have just started using jquery for the first time so i'm not sure if what i'm doing is correct. What i'm trying to do is very basic, I have a script which is adding a css watermark to textboxes upon load in an MVC view.

To select the element i do the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){$('#Department.DeptName').addWatermark('input-watermarked', 'test');});
```

Then in my script for adding the css watermarkclass it fails at the  "this.val().length" statement.

```
jQuery.fn.toggleWatermark = function(watermarkedClass, watermarkText) {
if (this.hasClass(watermarkedClass)) {
    this.removeWatermark(watermarkedClass);
}
else if (this.val().length == 0) {
    this.addClass(watermarkedClass);
    this.val(watermarkText);
}
```

}

The script works fine where an element id is "DepartmentDeptName", it's as if the selector doesn't work when the element id contains a dot inside it.  Does anyone know why or how to get around this issue?

Comment: Are you even allowed a full stop in a id attribute?

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Answer (score 68):

I think you should escape the dot with a double-backslash: `$("#Department\\.DeptName")` See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Escaping the dot can be done with two backslashes, as Joril said. There's another way of treating a dot as a literal, which is related but not appropriate for this question (hence, I'm posting this as a comment): if the offending selector bit is an attribute selector rather than a class or ID, you can wrap the entire thing in quotes to treat it as a literal: `$("input[name=department.deptname]")` doesn't work, but `$("input[name='department.deptname']")` does.

Comment: @Pauld'Aoust, that helped me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `#Department` with a class `DeptName`. You should escape with two backslashes (as Joril said).

See [JQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative syntaxes like `$("input[name='department.deptname']")` will work if you have control over writing jQuery. I am using Spring MVC with Kendo and thus I don't have access to jQuery code. Spring MVC `<form>` tag automatically puts `.` whereever applicable. E.g. if the user has Address.. thus field city will become `user.address.city` (or `address.city`). And if I break spring MVC into multiple forms then it messes up my back-end logic. It also scatters what should have been a single form. Another alternative is to flatten the `User` object on the back-end... again, not very clean. I am not sure but Dojo worked in such a scenario.