# How to get textarea value using jQuery for a div having name containing a dot('.')

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this case :

the HTML content(Note: the id contains a `.`):

```
<input id="register.address1" name="address1" class="text" value="" type="text">
```

the jQuery content:

```
$("#register.address1").css('display','none');
```

I am unable to make changes to this `register.address1` because it contains a `.`. I concluded it after replacing the `.` with a `-` gave me desired result.

But as I am not allowed to change the `register.address1` because the framework in which I am working does not allow me to do so. So what is other work around for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id

Comment: Similary question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3913170/1932746

Comment: I think writing this question was more effort than searching for an answer

Comment: You can use `$("div[id='register.address1']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [jquery selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) escape your id like,

```
$("#register\\.address1").css('display','none');
```

And to hide any element you can use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide) like,

```
$("#register\\.address1").hide();
```

```js
$('#register\\.address1').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="register.address1" name="address1" class="text" value="" type="text">
```