# jquery finding element by name (name has dot) showing Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im getting  `Syntax error, unrecognized expression:` whileing searching for input element has name "compl.name".

[image]

Comment: Add your code, both HTML and JS

Comment: use 
    jQuery('input[name^="complaintBrandDTO.name"]')

Comment: Escape the `.` [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ztLxn5tq/)

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913144/jquery-selector-not-working-when-element-contains-dot-in-tag-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters (such as `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ``) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector , it works

### Jquery Selector:

```
$("input[name='complaintBrandDTO.name']")
```

### Html

```
<input name="complaintBrandDTO.name" value="2"/>
```

### JsFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qzxedcut/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("input[name='complaintBrandDTO\\.name’]”);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote(`""`) the name value

```js
console.log($('[name^="abc.def"]').length);
//                  --^--   --^--
console.log($("[name^='abc.def']").length);
//                  --^--   --^--
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="abc.def"/><input name="abc.deff"/>
<!--                             --^--    --^-- -->
```

> Aa valid unquoted attribute value in HTML is any string of text that is not the empty string and that doesn’t contain spaces, tabs, line feeds, form feeds, carriage returns, ", ', `, =, <, or >. ( Taken from https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values )

**Update :** You can validate unquoted attribute value here https://mothereff.in/unquoted-attributes

Answer (score -1):

you need to escape the dot in selector...

Like this

```
$('[name^=hi\\.a]')
```