# Check if href contains a DOT using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I check if a href contains a string with a dot. I tried doing the following and it doesn't work:

```
$("td.children a[href*=board=9.0]").addClass("child9");
```

Any ideas on how I should do this?

Using

```
$("a[href*='=9.0']").hide();
```

Doesn't work, however this works fine but is not what I need:

```
$("a[href*=9]").hide();
```

This is a solution that works for me, but I would like to not have extra lines of code for every case:

```
$("td.children a[href*=9]").addClass("child9");
$("td.children a[href*=39]").removeClass("child9");
```

Here's some example of html on my site:

```
<a href="/index.php?board=1.0" title="No New Posts (Topics: 0, Posts: 0)" class="">BoardTitle_a</a>
<a href="/index.php?board=2.0" title="No New Posts (Topics: 0, Posts: 0)" class="">BoardTitle_b</a>
<a href="/index.php?board=3.0" title="No New Posts (Topics: 0, Posts: 0)" class="">BoardTitle_c</a>
<a href="/index.php?board=4.0" title="No New Posts (Topics: 0, Posts: 0)" class="">BoardTitle_d</a>
<a href="/index.php?board=5.0" title="No New Posts (Topics: 0, Posts: 0)" class="">BoardTitle_e</a>
```

I have these links from 1 to 39. I would like to select the one that has: board=9.0 without selecting the ones that have: board=19.0 etc

Comment: How does this not work? What else have you tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery selector not working when element contains dot in tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913144/jquery-selector-not-working-when-element-contains-dot-in-tag-name) also look here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: take the value of href , put into some variable then apply regex, you need to change workflow

Comment: *"however this works fine but is not what I need"* . How would we know what you need without you providing a [mcve]? We can't guess what specific problem is

Comment: @charlietfl If you read the OP, you will see that it says I need 9.0 not 9

Comment: And what are the test cases? You haven't provided any sample html to compare against or show us why your code isn't doing what you want

Comment: My code works without the ' ' but when I include them none of the code in that script tag works.

Comment: Then show us by example. Did you read the [mcve] link at all? Others are trying to help by giving you cases that work yet you haven't provided a single case that doesn't and we have to rely on guessing

Comment: @charlietfl I'm giving everything I know. Including the single quotes breaks everything and I have no idea why. I have no single quotes anywhere else in my code, this is the first time I've had to include them.

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated my post one last time with some code that does do what I need. However I would still like a simpler solution.

Comment: Sort of but not with any html we can see the actual issue with. We have no idea how complex your situation is. Might be as simple as `$('.cloud9').removeClass('cloud9');$("td.children a[href*='=" + someVariable+"']").addClass("child9");`

Comment: @charlietfl That doesn't seem to be any good either, I updated the OP with some html, not sure how useful it is.

Comment: *"doesn't seem to be any good either"* ... virtually meaningless to someone who can't see what you are working with or the higher level problem you are trying to solve. Create a demo that shows us and remember we can't see anything you are doing

Comment: @charlietfl I think I found the issue. single quotes are being stored as assci on my server. There are a few characters that do that and so I can't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you need to use `filter()` or `each()` in order to implement more advanced logic.

Example using [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and examining specific search param in href url

```js
$('a').removeClass('cloud9').filter(function(){
   var board = new URL(this.href).searchParams.get('board')
   return board  === '9.0';
}).addClass('cloud9')
```

```css
.cloud9 {color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="/index.php?board=9.0">9.0</a>
<a href="/index.php?board=39.0">39.0</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put the 9.0 inside single quotes - `$("a[href*='9.0']")`.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $("a[href*='9.0']").hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="19.01">9.0</a>

<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

Comment: @CianFlint This should work, but you can try `$("a[href*=9\\.0]").hide()`

Comment: What's the element `href`?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen that was the second thing I tried, and it's caused a bunch of other lines to give errors, and isn't working itself.

Comment: @CianFlint Then you have something else wrong, because this code should work just fine, make sure you have included jquery and so on. Check the console for errors

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen My code works fine when I do it without the .0, just the 9. However it hides other things I don't want it to, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @CianFlint Then please update your snippet so we can see the full context of your code.

Comment: @CianFlint What the `href` of the element you want to hide?

Comment: @Programmer I want to hide this: /index.php?board=9.0 but not this: /index.php?board=39.0

Comment: That's a total different question. Assuming my code hides the element, you can do it like this - `$("a[href*='=9.0']").hide()`.

Comment: also realized I need to include the board= part, but that still doesn't answer my original question

Comment: If you use the whole `href` - `$("a[href*='/index.php?board=9.0']").hide()`, is it working?

Comment: @Programmer nope, it's triggering errors in other parts of my code. I usually don't get many errors in the console, but whenever I include the ' ' it trips a bunch of errors from seemingly random places. No errors without the ' ' but just isn't what I need.

Comment: @Programmer I've updated my post with some code that works. But I'd like a simpler solution.