# How do I reference an element by name with [] brackets in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you reference a element in jquery BY NAME that has the [] in it.

```
<select name="values[]" multiple="true">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('[name=values[]]'); 
</script>
```

this should grab the element, but it does not work, I believe the [] in the name is messing it up, escaping it doesn't seem to work either.  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The HTML is incorrect. The only value the `multiple` attribute can take is `multiple`, `true` is an error.

Comment: Issue is reproducible in Firefox 3.6.17+
For the bug pls refer to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5482

Answer (score 10):

One way is to quote the name in the selector:

```
$('[name="values[]"]')
```

Or:

```
$("[name='values[]']")
```

Answer (score 5):

Related: [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Answer:
Use double backslashes to escape the brackets.

`$('[name="values[]"]');`

Edit: Revised the example for validity's sake. Apparently, Sizzle isn't handling the unquoted version well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me in Chrome.

If you run this code and look in the console you should see the elements

```
<select name="values[]" multiple="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // all the inputs with the name value
    console.log($('[name=values[]]'));

    // The first input with the name value
    console.log($('[name=values[]]')[0]);
</script>
```