# Escaping periods in xml element names with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have this xml document:

```
<subpages>
  <page.subpage>
    <title>blah</title>
  </page.subpage>
</subpages>
```

But when I try to loop through each `page.subpage`, nothing is returned.

```
$(xml).find("page.subpage").each(function() {
  console.log("found something!");
}
```

I'm guessing why nothing is returned has something to do with the period? I've tried html escaping it with `&#46;` but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(xml).find("page\\.subpage").each(function() {
  console.log("found something!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the XML selector? How are you setting that up? Try running it through with some kind of javascript debugger (firebug?) and see if you are ever even getting into the each function.