# Select elements with periods in ID using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have an id with a dot ('.') . I am not able to select it using jQuery.

For example:

```
 <p id="sec.ond">this is another  paragraph</p>
```

How can I use such an id to select this element?

I get such ids while I use spring forms with arrays, e.g.:

```
<form:input path="abc[0].firstName" />
```

This will result in:

```
<form:input id="abc0.firstName" name="abc[0].firstName" />
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Thanks , I couldnt find it when I searched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can escape it to select it in jQuery.

Example:

```
$('#sec\\.ond').doSomething()
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/C7qhF/
See Also: [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Answer (score 3):

Use two backslashes before the period to escape it, e.g.:

```
$('#sec\\.ond')
```

See ["How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?"](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) in the jQuery FAQ.

Comment: I tried with single slash, didnt get idea for double slash. Thanks