# How to shield "." char?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

I tried to run the following code:

```
$('#info-mail.ru .domain-info').toggle();
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/dizpers/7wFWH/)

And #info-mail.ru as I understood interpreted as id="info-mail" and class="ru", but I have the following structure:

```
<div id="info-mail.ru">
    <p class="domain-info">
        Some cool info
        Some cool info
        Some cool info
        Some cool info
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I shield "." char in selector statement? Or the only way is to replace all "." with "_" (for example)?

TIA!

Comment: Interestingly, the `.` is technically valid in an ID: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/70579)

Comment: @Pekka: checking that was my first intuition as well ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape `.` with a double backslash, one for the literal and the other for jQuery:

```
$('#info-mail\\.ru .domain-info').toggle();
```

See [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F) for details.

Comment: Remove last \\ : $('#info-mail\\.ru .domain-info').toggle(); The last one is intended to be a class selector.

Comment: thx! work perfect! could you explain - where this "shield" syntax is described (i.e. "\\" )?

Comment: @dizpers - They're not called shield characters but **escape characters**

Comment: @dizpers - See [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F). It boils down to expressing \ with a literal which jQuery interprets as a command to escape the next character, in this case `.`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to use two backslashes before the .

So the selector would be `$('#info-mail\\.ru .domain-info').toggle();`