# Jquery unable to find div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div in my application with an id of `financial[terms]`, but jquery does not seem to be able to target this.

Is this a semantically invalid id?

Comment: I've never seen an HTML ID with square brackets `[]` before. Not to mention that square brackets are part of jQuery selector syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The HTML 4.01 spec states](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) that ID tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens (-), underscores (_), colons (:), and periods (.).

To precisely answer your question, your `id` is invalid in HTML 4.01

[According to this article, in HTML 5](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class) however, your `id` looks like it could be valid.

- [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)
- [HTML 5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute)

**EDIT:**

It should be noted that jQuery itself may still have some trouble with certain aspects of a *valid* HTML 4.01 `id`, such as periods and colons.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

So, no, your id is not semantically valid.

Comment: This is interesting. I'm not sure how colons or periods in the id would be interpreted by JQuery, since they're part of JQuery selector syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a semantically invalid id?

I would say yes, use something more like `financial-terms`.

Answer (score 0):

While it's invalid in IDs (but fine in name attributes), you can probably get away with it if you want.  You need to [escape special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id), as the square brackets have their own meaning in jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely invalid.
An id can start with a letter, and be followed by letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), and underscores ("_").

Comment: ... and colons and periods...  you must be getting your information from the w3schools.  See [http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: I know colons and periods are valid characters in an ID but I'm not sure how they can be used in this context, since they're part of JQuery selector syntax.

Comment: The answer to this question, _"Is this a semantically invalid id?"_, is straightforward.

Comment: I agree. I was just commenting on it's practicality.

Answer (score 0):

Id naming rules from W3.org:

- First character: `[A-Za-z]`
- Rest of the characters: `[A-Za-z],[0-9],"-","_",":" or "."`

[Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name)

Comment: Another perfect example where W3Schools falls short by providing incomplete information.  [See the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name).  And then read [this](http://w3fools.com).

Comment: @Sparky672 Thank's, I didn't know that before. IMHO they do have the clearest way to describe HTML/CSS specs, too bad the information itself seems to be lacking. My eyes have been opened now!

Comment: It's just a pity the real W3 site isn't as easy to use as the W3schools site. But yes, though these days W3schools is much better than it used to be I still avoid it so that I don't have to try to remember which parts are correct and which are not.

Comment: valid or not, i wouldn't want to name my element as `financial:first` for instance. Especially if i'm working with jquery :p

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the `ID`, you can still use `document.getElementById` inside jQuery or (worse performance) use `$("[id='financial[terms]'")`.

Comment: jQuery aside, it's not valid HTML anyway unless he's using HTML 5.

Comment: TBH, validity doesn't matter.  Sure it's great to be valid, but if it works in every browser (and it does) there's no reason to do a major refactor if it's like that all over his app.

Comment: Validity compliance always matters... it's a major factor in keeping your site from breaking when newer browsers are released.  Since comments are not for discussion, this is where I'm leaving it.