# jQuery attribute contains selector with text containing slashes

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a jQuery selector to find links to files contained in a `documents` folder.  There are several documents folders in various places on the site.  A sample URL to match is

```
http://example.com/magazine/volume5/documents/magazine2010_11-8_final.pdf
```

This works:

```
$("a[href*='documents']")
```

But for completeness, I want to match the slashes on either side.  I see that to include a slash in a selector, I need to prefix it with two backslashes, like this: `\\/`.  But that's working only for the trailing slash, not the leading slash.

This works:

```
$("a[href*='documents\\/']")
```

But this does not:

```
$("a[href*='\\/documents\\/']")
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
On jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jA3AJ/), it works, but not on my site (using the same browser, Firefox 4.0).  My full code snippet is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Instrument download links for GA
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[href*='\\/documents\\/']").click(function () {
            alert("Download: " + this.pathname);
            // if (typeof _gaq !== 'undefined') { _gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Files", "Download", this.pathname]); }
        });
    });
</script>
```

According to the answer to this [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id), I need to use two backslashes.  The jsFiddle works for me either way.  In fact, it works with no backslashes: `$("a[href*='/documents/'])"`

**Updated**
I'm using jQuery 1.6.4.  I updated the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jA3AJ/1/ and there, it works fine.

Comment: Both versions are working for me, both with the current quote setup and reversing them as shown in api.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/ykvw5/

Comment: Are the anchor tags added to the page dynamically?

Comment: No.  They're in the static markup.

Answer (score 2):

Its works for me. Use `$("a[href*='\/documents\/']")`. If you want to escape a forward slash just put one escape character(`\`) in front of it. You don't need 2 escape characters.

Wroking [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jA3AJ/)

Comment: I didn't even see the second escape... Need new contacts

Comment: On jsfiddle, all versions work -- one or two slashes, any order of quotes.  I'll update my question with more code.

Comment: If `$("a[href*='/documents/'])"` works they why are you putting the slash?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse your single and double quotes

```
$('a[href*="\/documents\/"]')
```

Comment: Reversing the quotes made no difference.