# jQuery dot in ID selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select html nodes by ID with jquery when the id contains a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)

I have a website that contains elements similar to this:

```
<p id="root.SomeCoolThing">Some Cool Thing</p>
```

I can not select the paragraph with jQuery like `$('#root.SomeCoolThing')` because jQuery thinks, `SomeCoolThing` is the class of an element with `id="root"`.

How can I select this element with jQuery? I would like to avoid a construction like this:

```
$(document.getElementById('root.SomeCoolThing'))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Though there is a solution with double `\\\`. Why put a dot inside the id?

Comment: Well, the website is not made from me. I do not like the ID-names either. It is, more precisely, an API documentation.

Comment: There's nothing horrid about it- it's a perfectly valid selector according to the specifications. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Use the escaping rules from the [jQuery selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as follows:

```
$('#root\\.SomeCoolThing')
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters (such as 
>   `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~ ``) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with
>   `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Tried it using a single backslash which did not work. Thank you!

Comment: I tried $('#root\\.SomeCoolThing'), it works. But when I try $("#root\\.SomeCoolThing") with double-quotes, it didn't work. Do you have any idea about the difference between single-quote and double-quotes in jQuery?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm have two or more dots in the id.

Comment: @charlietfl Please note, dot notation with backslashes is much quicker: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selectors-perf-test

Answer (score 56):

Using attr works:

```
$('p[id="root.SomeCoolThing"]')
```

Comment: 'One-liners' sometimes aren't useful enough. Explain your thinking beyond a simple statement...

Comment: This is also a lot of extra processing on jQuery's part that is unnecessary, where all you really need to do is escape the "." character...

Comment: @Ian. It is useful when you do not know the id beforehand. It could be a variable you get from a json object.

Answer (score 19):

You need to escape special chars:

```
$('#root\\.SomeCoolThing')
```

[docs:](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~** ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \\. For example, if you have an element with **id="foo.bar",** you can use the selector **$("#foo\\.bar").**

Answer (score 8):

You can escape period using something like this

```
$("#root\\.SomeCoolThing")
```

[How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/ba072168939b245a?pli=1

Answer (score 4):

Shooting from the hip here, but if you cannot change the ID of the element, try using this selector:

```
$("p[id=root.SomeCoolThing]")
```

Comment: Not without `""`: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: p[id=details_it.airgap.vault]`

Answer (score 3):

Use two backslashes before each special character

```
  $('#root\\.SomeCoolThing')
```