# Jquery mobile - page id's with a dot inside don't fire on pageinit

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a valid and working page that begins with this definition:

```js
div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="alkohol.test" data-url="alkohol.test" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-b ui-page-header-fixed iscroll-page ui-page-active" >
```

This is called properly and being displayed like it should but it seems not to fire on page init event. My code:

```js
$( '#alkohol.test' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){

console.log("Test successfully loaded!");
});
```

When I change the page id to "alkoholtest" then it fires on pageinit. I assume that dots aren't allowed and I think that it's all about jquery selectors that expects id "alkohol" followed by the class "test" - but I want it to react to the page id being called. 
Is there a workaround for this problem? 
I mean without changing the dot to something else because I've got tons of code that will be a nightmare to change. Escaping or something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Pawel put this as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here:
[How to select html nodes by ID with jquery when the id contains a dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot)
and here:
[jQuery dot in ID selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930577/jquery-dot-in-id-selector)

you have to escape the dot which makes jQuery treat 'test' as a class name

```js
$('#alkohol\\.test')
```

or make sure that the whole string is understood as an ID

```js
$("div[id='alkohol.test']")
```

Comment: Oh wow, this was a fast answered one. Thank you Paweł, this is exactly what I was searching for. I previously tried to escape it the php-regex-style with one a single backslash but i never came to try it with double backslashes. Thanx again and greetings to my old homeland Poland.