# Dynamically created table row element cannot refer using Id with jquery

Tags: jquery

I cannot read the dynamically added  from my edit method. The rows are dynamically added and the rows contains span with Id. I am trying to read the content of the span from another jquery method. Both the methods are given below.

```
function AddQuestionChoice() {
    var table = $("#questionOptionsTable");
    var index = $('#questionOptionsTable tr').length - 1;
    var choiceSequenceNo = $("#choiceSequenceNo").val();
    var choiceText = $("#choiceText").val();

    if (!$("#choiceSequenceNo").val())
    {
        alert("Enter sequence number");
        return;
    }

    if (!$("#choiceText").val())
    {
        alert("Enter choice");
        return;
    }

    if (!$.isNumeric(choiceSequenceNo))
    {
        alert("Enter valid sequence number.")
        return;
    }

    var row = "<tr bgcolor='#fff'><td id='choiceDiv[" + index + "]'> <span name= 'eventSurveyQuestion.Sequences[" + index + "]' id='eventSurveyQuestion.Sequences[" + index + "]'>" + choiceSequenceNo + "</span> &nbsp;</td><td> <span name='eventSurveyQuestion.Options[" + index + "]' id='eventSurveyQuestion.Options[" + index + "]'>" + choiceText + "</span> &nbsp;</td>" +
                     "<td><a href='javascript:EditQuestionChoice(" + index + ");'><img src='/Content/themes/Default/images/action1.png'></a> <a href='javascript:RemoveQuestionChoice(" + index + ");'><img src='/Content/themes/Default/images/action2.png'></a></td></tr>";

    $('#questionOptionsTable').append(row);

    var length = $('#questionOptionsTable tr').length;
    $("#choiceSequenceNo").val(length);
    $("#choiceText").val('');

}
function EditQuestionChoice(index)
{
    var sequenceNumber = $("#eventSurveyQuestion.Sequences["+index + "]").text();
    alert(sequenceNumber);
    var choiceText = $("#eventSurveyQuestion.Options["+ index +"]").text();
    $("#choiceSequenceNo").val(sequenceNumber);
    $("#choiceText").val(choiceText);
}
```

Comment: The question is the order of the two events: when is it created and when is it called? Can you show more of your code?

Comment: `$('#someId').text()` will return the text. `$('#someId').text('stuff')` will replace the text with stuff. currently your example works http://jsfiddle.net/1euaLup3/

Comment: I have a button in my page to add the content from text boxes to the table. That time I am adding to the row.

Comment: But I have an edit button in the row which calls another jquery method to refer the span element. It does not seems. I suspect my span is not registered in the DOM?

Comment: Then, I think the problem is not the span (which IS in the DOM), but the newly created edit button. When you create buttons dynamically, you must make sure that the buttons have the proper function attached.

Comment: Actually that part is also correct.  My question is, is the way I am doing is correct?

Comment: I should work, but if you don't show the code, we're just guessing. Take a look here. Are you doing something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/p9stwexd/1/

Comment: I am  a newbie here. Can I just add my code as comment?

Comment: You can EDIT your question and put the code there.

Comment: Please see my code below.

Comment: Are you sure the formula for the index value is correct? Did you check what ids are generated in the DOM?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The reason is I tried by hard coding the index as zero which is the index of the first row.

Comment: Id are generated as expected. Any other alternative I can try?

Comment: See my answer. You need to escape ALL problematic characters! That includes "[" and "]". You CAN NOT use "#questSequence[0]" in jQuery. Use "#questSequence\\\[0\\\]" (double \\\)

Comment: Do I need to add it in both places?
ie, in 

 var row = "<tr bgcolor='#fff'><td ......line and

EditQuestionChoice method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that in jQuery the dot (.) is reserved for class names. So your span has a problematic id:

```
"#eventSurveyQuestion.Sequence[..."
```

When you use:

```
var choiceText = $("#eventSurveyQuestion.Options["+ index +"]").text();
```

jQuery will look for "#eventSurveyQuestion" with a ".Sequence" class, instead of an id of "#eventSurveyQuestion.Sequence".

Try instead (use escape rules):

```
var choiceText = $("#eventSurveyQuestion\\.Options\\["+ index +"\\]").text();
```

Note: you need to escape ALL problematic characters: . [ and ]

See proof here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvz64bLp/1/)

See explanation here: [jQuery dot in ID selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9930611/4902724)

Comment: No luck so far, I tried with escape rules. Also changed the id to just seqtext and optText. Still not working so it is that.

Comment: Immediately after added the row to the table, I tried to get the value, even there it is not getting. As zero will be the index for the first row, I did like the following. Note: I had changed the id as 'questSequence[' + index + "]"

$('#questionOptionsTable').append(row);
            alert($("#questSequence[0]").text());

Comment: You need to escape ALL problematic characters! That includes "[" and "]". You CAN NOT use "#questSequence[0]" in jQuery. Use "#questSequence\\[0\\]" (double \\)

Comment: Finally! I'm glad. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 1):

`text` is a jquery function and not a property, use `$("#someId").text()` to get the value of the span.

Make sure you have jquery loaded and your code is within a `ready` function :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var row= "<tr><td><span id='someId'>spancontent</span></td></tr>";
  $('#table').append(row);
  
   $('#rowText').click(function(){
   
     alert($("#someId").text());
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1"></table>

<a href="#" id="rowText">View row text</a>
```

Comment: Yes it is a typo, please ignore.

Comment: In other words, Can I refer the element with in the row I added with  $('#table').append(row) from another jquery method?

Comment: Yes you can, just make sure you do it after the append so that you guarantee the element have been added to the DOM.