# scroll to element using two parents, one with id and the other with class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this line of code to try and scroll to an element by its title:

```
  $("#wrapper").animate({scrollTop: $(".placementName[title='" + placementName + "']").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
```

but the problem is i have few objects in my HTML code with the same title and same class `placementName`, how can i ad an id to the rule?
the id is `somewebsite.com` so i tried something like:

```
$("#wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$("#somewebsite.com.placementName[title='" + placementName + "']").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
```

but it didn't work...any idea? thx

Comment: Try `...#somewebsite\.com.placementName...` I seem to remember you have to escape a period in an id

Comment: It needs 2 \\ so: `#somewebsite\\.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you want is

```
$("#somewebsite\\.com.placementName[title='" + placementName + "']")
```

That is because you need to escape `.` jquery reads `$("#somewebsite.com.placementName")` as id: `#somewebsite` and classes: `.com` `.placementName`

Someone wrote here that `somewebsite.com` is not valid id. That is not true. More here https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2672983

If id `somewebsite.com` is unique, just use

```
$("#somewebsite\\.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do :

```
  $("#wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$("#somewebsite\\.com").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
```

Since the id should be unique and is all you need to specify the element.
The dot in the id can be problematic, but escaping the dot should work.

See also: [jQuery dot in ID selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930577/jquery-dot-in-id-selector)

Answer (score 0):

If you have dots in your id, you can access checking the attribute, like this:

```
$("#wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$("[id='somewebsite.com'].placementName[title='" + placementName + "']").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
```

Anyway, since ids must be unique, checking the id should be enough:

```
$("#wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$("[id='somewebsite.com']").offset().top - 10}, "slow");
```

Answer (score -1):

`somewebsite.com` is not a valid id. Please change it and then it should work.
When you do this `:$("#somewebsite.com.placementName[title='" + placementName + "']")` then jquery looks for a dom with id `somewebsite` and classes `com` & `placementName`

Comment: IDs can have a period (dot) in them but they are problematic

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes but if u use them directly in jquery selector. the selector interpret as a class after ther dot. so you can not directly use it for selection. I didnt know that OP cant change the `id` as the easiest way is to change the id if possible.

Comment: Yes you can, as my comment says, you escape the period e.g. `#unique\.id`

Comment: I never said you posted a wrong answer. sure we can escape.