# Why dies JQuery throw a syntax error on compound names?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a legacy web app, that's using JQuery.

There's a place where we're trying to save all of the form data to local storage, before we redirect to a different page, so that we can restore it when we return.

This pattern is working on a number of pages:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var searchForm = $('form.full-investigation');
    var searchFormElements = searchForm.find(':input');

    var saveSearchElements = function saveSearchElements() {
        var saveData = [];
        searchFormElements.each(function(index, element) {
            var item = $(element);
            var name = element.name;
            var value = item.val();
            var type = element.type;
            var add = true;
            if (type === "checkbox") {
                value = element.checked;
            } else if (type === "radio") {
                if (!element.checked) {
                    add = false;
                }
            }
            if (add) {
                saveData.push({ name: name, value: value });
            }
        });

        var serialized = JSON.stringify(saveData);
        sessionStorage.setItem('FullInvestigation_criteria', serialized);
    };

    var loadSearchElements = function loadSearchElements(serializedForm) {
        var foundOne = false;

        if (serializedForm) {
            var saveData = JSON.parse(serializedForm);

            for (var i = 0; i < saveData.length; i++) {
                var key = saveData[i].name;
                var value = saveData[i].value;

                try {
                    var element = searchForm.find(':input[name=' + key + ']');

                    if (element.length > 1) {

                        for (var j = 0; j < element.length; j++) {
                            var each = element[j];
                            var type = each.type;
                            if (type === 'radio' && each.value === value) {
                                each.checked = true;
                                foundOne = true;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        element.val(value);

                        if (value)
                            foundOne = true;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    var msg = e;
                }
            }
        }

        return foundOne;
    };

    $("#redirectbutton").on('click',
        function(event) {
        try {
            saveSearchElements();
        } catch (e) {
        }
    });

    var fullInvestigation_criteria = sessionStorage.getItem('FullInvestigation_criteria');
    loadSearchElements(fullInvesigation_criteria);
    sessionStorage.setItem('FullInvesigation_criteria', '{}');
});
```

As I said, this is working on a number of pages.

But when I try to use it on a different page, where it had not been used before, I'm getting syntax errors. The problem is that on this new page, saveSearchElements() encounters :input elements with dotted names. E.g., ticketAndMarking.actualnearinter. So we're saving name/value pair with a key of "ticketAndMarking.actualnearinter"

So when we process that key in
And then when we call loadSearchElements, and it processes that key, the line:
var element = searchForm.find(':input[name=' + key + ']');
throws an exception with the message:
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :input[name=ticketAndMarking.actualnearinter]

Answer (score 0):

I was asking this question for the group, but found the answer before I posted.

So here it is, in case anyone else runs into something similar:

[jQuery dot in ID selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930577/jquery-dot-in-id-selector)

Having a period in an element name is perfectly acceptable. But JQuery selector syntax requires that they be escaped.

The fix in the code above is simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < saveData.length; i++) {
    var key = saveData[i].name.replace(".", "\\.");
    var value = saveData[i].value;
```