# jQuery ID selection with React generate components

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bookmarklet

I'm trying to make a few bookmarkets for Zendesk --
One of the problems I am running across is using jQuery for ID selection.

Given the following HTML:

```html
<label data-garden-id="forms.input_label" data-garden-version="8.69.11" id="64val-field_2.1.0--label" for="64val-field_2.1.0--input" data-garden-container-id="containers.field" data-garden-container-version="2.1.0" class="sc-1gau0qu-1 gGZrXf StyledLabel-sc-2utmsz-0 bYrRLL">Project ID</label>
<input data-garden-id="forms.input" data-garden-version="8.69.11" aria-invalid="false" id="64val-field_2.1.0--input" aria-labelledby="64val-field_2.1.0--label" data-test-id="ticket-fields-text-field" data-tracking-id="ticket-fields-text-field" type="text" class="sc-1gau0qu-2 gEiOHk StyledTextInput-sc-k12n8x-0 bXXlCE" value="foo">
```

I figure the easiest way for me to find the input field value is to use the label `for` attribute.

```js
$("label:contains('Project ID')").attr("for") // returns '65val-field_2.1.0--input'
```

I would assume I could use this as the direct ID selector by prepending `'#'`.

But it fails with the direct id selector:

```js
$('#' + $("label:contains('Project ID')").attr("for")); // the length is `0`
```

This works with:

```js
document.getElementById($("label:contains('Project ID')").attr("for"));
```

It also works with:

```js
$('input[id="'+ $("label:contains('Project ID')").attr("for") + '"]')[0]
```

While I can workaround this issue with `getElementByID`, I'm curious why the jQuery selector won't work -- am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I ran some tests and it looks like using `$('#'` doesn't like that the ID has periods in it. You can try it by using your example HTML and remove the periods from the ID/for.

Comment: Looks like you aren't the first to have this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930577/jquery-dot-in-id-selector and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605630/how-to-select-html-nodes-by-id-with-jquery-when-the-id-contains-a-dot

Comment: Thanks folks. I knew it was something obvious I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [escape the selector](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/). The culprit is the `64val-field_2.1.0--input` (dot characters in the `id` and `for` attribute values).

Here is a jQuery plugin I created that returns an input associated with a label.

```js
(function() {
  $.formElementByLabel = function(label) {
    var $label = $('label:contains("' + label + '")');
    var formElementId = $label.attr("for");
    return $('#' + $.escapeSelector(formElementId));
  };
})(jQuery)

const $input = $.formElementByLabel("Project ID");

console.log($input.val()); // foo
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="sc-1gau0qu-1 gGZrXf StyledLabel-sc-2utmsz-0 bYrRLL" id="64val-field_2.1.0--label" for="64val-field_2.1.0--input" data-garden-id="forms.input_label" data-garden-version="8.69.11" data-garden-container-id="containers.field" data-garden-container-version="2.1.0">Project ID</label>
<input type="text" class="sc-1gau0qu-2 gEiOHk StyledTextInput-sc-k12n8x-0 bXXlCE" id="64val-field_2.1.0--input" value="foo" data-garden-id="forms.input" data-garden-version="8.69.11" aria-invalid="false" aria-labelledby="64val-field_2.1.0--label" data-test-id="ticket-fields-text-field"
  data-tracking-id="ticket-fields-text-field">
```

Comment: Thanks - I totally overlooked the selector naming with it automatically escaping in the other method.