# Why doesn't this jquery selector with a period work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a div with an ID

```
<div id="updates-pane-user.followed_on">
```

this jquery selector works

```
$("[id^='updates-pane']")
```

but this doesn't

```
$("#updates-pane-user.followed_on")
```

I don't see what is wrong.. id names can include periods right? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I found this that might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id

Comment: that should work, something else must be wrong.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: have you tried without the period?

Comment: Just tried it myself. Yeap, it's not working. Though all your characters should be valid.

Comment: this seems highly incompatible design. well maybe not highly, but annoying

Comment: The double-backslash method from @jlg1987 's link works. `$('#updates-pane.user\\.followed_on')` successfully selects the `div`.

Comment: @NickGinanto Actually, it matches the behavior of CSS selectors exactly. How else would you select an element that has both the id and the class?

Comment: Even though it may be allowed, it's best to avoid adding these characters in the ID attribute - simply because it's not good practice  with jQuery :) Good question though, +1!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the latter selector, `.` is used to denote a class. So it's looking for the `.followed_on` class, which it obviously doesn't find and so nothing is matched.

In order to fix this, I think you should escape the dot with a **double-backslash**:

`$("#updates-pane-user\\.followed_on")`

According  to the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

In general, try **not** to use periods or other special characters in your IDs to avoid confusion all around. "Allowed" is not the same as "good practice."

Comment: but according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html it may include periods

Comment: Yep, they just don't say what the jQuery docs say - try **two** backslashes :)

Comment: @NickGinanto The ID may have a period, yes. But jQuery assumes it means a class when put inside a selector, so you have to escape it. In general, try NOT to use periods or other special characters in your IDs to avoid confusion all around. "Allowed" is not the same as "good practice."

Comment: Thanks for fixing that @Blazemonger - obviously SO pastes don't always work well ;) I'll add your advisement also.

Comment: @Blazemonger: And not only jQuery, but also CSS.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the dot in the `id` attribute which in jQuery syntax represents class selector.
This selector is equivalent to selecting node as:

`<div id="updates-pane-user" class="followed_on">`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, HTML5 allows period in id but jQuery isn't built by the w3 org. It's just a utility library optimized for the most common cases.

If your ID has a period, or any other character making jQuery parse it as more than just an id, then you'd better use the standard function :

```
$(document.getElementById(yourId))
```

This is the preferred solution if your id comes from a variable.

Answer (score 4):

`$("#updates-pane-user\\.followed_on")` - *This Should work as per the [Jquery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)*

```
// Does not work
 $("#some:id")

 // Works!
 $("#some\\:id")

 // Does not work
 $("#some.id")

 // Works!
 $("#some\\.id")
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.` selector considers that there is a class with the following name

```
$("#updates-pane-user.followed_on")
```

means : find all elements with id = `updates-pane-user` which have class name `followed_on`

Answer (score 2):

Use this to escape your dot:

```
$("#updates-pane-user\\.followed_on")
```

Reference: http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F

Answer (score 2):

For sure period creating problem for JQuery to recognise the pattern.

jQuery has three type of selectors:

1. `"."` selector means to select an element by class name.
2. `"#"` selector means to select an element by ID.
3. And Element selector that selects elements by their name(`div`, `input`
   etc.)

And you have confused `jQuery engine` with your naming convention of ID.

Its assuming that there is a div with `id="updates-pane-user"` and a applied `class="followed_on"`. In such cases `jQuery` suggest to escape sequence using `//`. Below should be your syntex to select the element.

```
$("#updates-pane-user\\.followed_on");
```

Check it out this wrong fiddle and try to correct using `//` : http://jsfiddle.net/ukJ8Z/

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

yes Jimbo answer is correct, but you can still make that work with escaping character with `\\`

```
$("#updates-pane-user\\.followed_on")
```

Escape with TWO (2) backslashes.

Check this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How%5Fdo%5FI%5Fselect%5Fan%5Felement%5Fthat%5Fhas%5Fweird%5Fcharacters%5Fin%5Fits%5FID.3F) for `How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?`

Comment: The double backslash *was part of my original answer*, so not sure why you put "... **but** you can still make that work with escaping character with \\" ;)

Comment: @Jimbo, yes i think you updated your answer after adding backslash becoz i dint find it initially. `so not sure why you put "`. What do you meant? i dint understand

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the id attribute selector, like:

```
$('[id="updates-pane-user.followed_on"]')
```

because jQuery will treat the attribute as a string, rather than a jQuery class selector.