# jQuery $("#" + x) does not work, but document.getElementById(x) works

Tags: javascript, jquery

### The problem

I'm trying to change the inner HTML value of an element. I've not used jQuery really much and I'm still a novice in many aspects of its functionalities.

```
    $('a.toggle-download').live('click', function (event) { 
        $.post("/ajax/toggle-download", { code: $(this).data("document"), prev_value: $(this).data("val") })
        .done(function(data) {
            var json = data,
            obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
            if(obj['return'] == 1){
                //document.getElementById("p_" + obj['code']).innerHTML = 'some text';
                $("#p_" + obj['code']).html('some text');
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

I've tried both lines, first the jQuery one through `$("#p_" + obj['code'])`, which did not work and then through `document.getElementById("p_" + obj['code'])` which works perfectly.

It seems I'm missing something obvious here, but still i don't understand why jquery does not work in this case!

### The question

Why does the plain old javascript work correctly, when jQuery does not?

### Additional informations

1) jQuery itself works and it's correctly loaded. No conflicts are present: the ajax call is sent successfully and the answer is correctly received,

2) The received ID exists and it's unique

3) I'm not keen on [jQuery html() method](http://api.jquery.com/html/) but i followed the documentation and it should work as i used it

### System information

This problem presents itself while using Chrome 27.0.1453.116 m. I didn't tested it with other versions or other browsers, but i'm quite sure to presume that's a jQuery problem rather than a browser problem. Also, i'm using php 5.3 on apache, but again these info should not be relevant to the problem.

If I missed some information you need to better understand my problem, please let me know in the comments and I'll try to answer you as soon as i can. Also, please forgive my bad grammar but I'm not a native english speaker.

### Answers to comments

as requested, here's an example of the ajax response:
`{"return":1,"code":"5.43.321"}`

the command `console.log($("#p_" + obj['code']).length)` yields "0"

Comment: What's in `obj['code']` ? There are many strings that make the selector invalid for jquery.

Comment: Yes, show us what `obj['code']` contains and we could help you better

Comment: Please check the console once with this code `console.log($("#p_" + obj['code']).length)` inside if statement....

Comment: @dystroy, edited my question with the requested info

Comment: try `$("#p_" + obj['code'] + "")`

Comment: @PalashMondal see latest edit

Comment: +1 for a question how it should be.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id

Comment: @Christoph thank you. I'm more often playing the part of the answerer than the questioner, but I really couldn't look myself in the mirror if I wrote a bad question after handing out so many -1s around!

Comment: @JoeFrambach Thank you! That's perfect. You should post it as an answer and elaborate it a little so i can upvote it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Your id is `p_x.xx.xxx` then `$('#' + id)` means: element with the id `p_x` and classes `xx` and `xxx`.

Either replace the dots with `\\.` before using the string as id ore use the approach suggested by @dystroy.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be the issue!

Comment: your answer is basically correct, but i need to replace the periods with `\\.` rather than `\.`! please, edit the answer :)

Comment: I spent so much time trying to figure out why it wasn't detecting my fields generated by asp.net-core and had a '.' on the id. Pretty much jQuery thought it was a class

Answer (score 4):

When you want to select an element using an arbitrary string as ID, you'd better avoid using a `'#'+yourstring` selector : in many cases this can make a selector invalid for jQuery even while your string is a valid HTML5 id.

If your id contains a dot, jQuery will interpret it as the start of a class.

Prefer this :

```
$(document.getElementById(yourstring))
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Can you please explain why does the approach `# + string` causes this wrong behavior?

Comment: The string has to be parsed and jQuery has to recognize the id part. But in HTML5 you can put > or # or so many characters in an id that many selectors can't be interpreted (to be more precise, you'd need to escape the characters specifically for the selector).

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I've marked zeroflagL's one as accepted because it explained WHY the current selector was not working. Anyway your answer works perfectly and i gave it a +1

Comment: Well... I had explained it too... but no worry.

Comment: Yeah but you said that it may be interpreted as invalid, which is 100% correct, but did not say WHY it was invalid in this case :)

Comment: @STTLCU Read the comment above (the second one after the answer, made before you gave your exact id) and this sentence in my answer : `If your id contains a dot, jQuery will interpret it as the start of a class.`. But again, it doesn't really matter, I'm just surprised you found something more in the other answer that what I had already given in my answer or my comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("[id='p_"+code+"']")
```

This will also work. It contains the periods in the id string.

Comment: My doctype is already as you specified. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Sorry I realized that answer wouldn't help so I deleted it and tried something else. Didn't think anyone would notice oops

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I've marked zeroflagL's one as accepted because it explained WHY the current selector was not working. Your answer got my personal second place, but i can't award it except for a simple +1. FYI, i'll probably end using this code in my project, if that's a consolation :D

Answer (score 2):

This actually works for me...

```
<div id="p_testdiv1"></div>


var obj = { code : 'testdiv1' }

console.log(obj.code);

//document.getElementById("p_" + obj.code).innerHTML = "test"; // Also works

$("#p_" + obj.code).html("test1"); // Displays "test1" in the div
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hZ4yz/

Comment: I've tried hardcoding the string in my code, but it does not solve the issue

Comment: Seems like a strange scenario, when you do a console.log of the jQuery element console.log($("#p_" + yourVal)) what does it show, does it find the element on your page?

Comment: I suppose the problem is because of dots in the id interpreted as classes, as others suggested

Comment: Ahh, yes, that would certainly do it.