# jQuery with the plus sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I wonder why jQuery doesn't allow "+" sign. Here is an example of how it works with "1" and "3" but not with "2+". Just mouse-over the text above every div.

```
<div id="div-2+"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53spt4hb/)

```js
$('a.hover').mouseover(function() {

    dataI = $(this).data('i');

 $('div#div-' + dataI).addClass('h');

});

$('a.hover').mouseout(function() {

    dataI = $(this).data('i');

 $('div#div-' + dataI).removeClass('h');

});
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 60px 20px 60px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.h {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="hover" data-i="1">DIV 1</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="2+">DIV 2+</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="3">DIV 3</a>

<br />

<div id="div-1"></div>

<div id="div-2+"></div>

<div id="div-3"></div>
```

Comment: I haven't lost too much sleep over this yet

Comment: Please bring the reproducing code here. An off-site link is insufficient. Also, tag JavaScript as such.

Comment: See [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/350292/218196)

Comment: It sounds like a Very Bad Idea to use the option name to create the option id.  What if your user enters the same option name twice? If you save each option to a database, try using `id="id-{{database-id}}"` : it will be both unique and a good value to use as an id.

Comment: @JK. I know but here I use one row with 3 fields for option titles and option values:

poll-id / "Option 1|-|Option 2|-|Option 3" / "0-0-0"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most-likely because [the plus sign is the adjacent CSS selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean), which causes the Sizzle selector library jQuery uses to assume you mean an adjacent selector.

One way around this would be to use an attribute selector, that selects the `id` attribute. Although many people would argue putting a plus sign in the `id` is a bad idea.

## Working Example:

```js
$('a.hover').mouseover(function() {

    dataI = $(this).data('i');

 $('div[id="div-' + dataI + '"]').addClass('h');

});

$('a.hover').mouseout(function() {

    dataI = $(this).data('i');

 $('div[id="div-' + dataI + '"]').removeClass('h');

});
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 60px 20px 60px 0;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.h {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="hover" data-i="1">DIV 1</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="2+">DIV 2+</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="3">DIV 3</a>

<br />

<div id="div-1"></div>

<div id="div-2+"></div>

<div id="div-3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and for the "+" in the id I know it's bad practice but in my case it's a polls app where people create their own polls with some options to chose from and the id will be the lowercase version of the option. everything goes well until I made a poll asking for the favorite IDE or editor where I put "Notepad++" and got the problem. And even the other options after it are gone from the form submit. It's very hard to discuss that exact point here.

Answer (score 2):

Note, "workaround"

Try utilizing `css`

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 60px 20px 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

a.hover[data-i="1"]:hover ~ div[id$="1"],
a.hover[data-i="2+"]:hover ~ div[id$="2+"],
a.hover[data-i="3"]:hover ~ div[id$="3"] {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<a class="hover" data-i="1">DIV 1</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="2+">DIV 2+</a>

<a class="hover" data-i="3">DIV 3</a>

<br />

<div id="div-1" class="hover"></div>

<div id="div-2+" class="hover"></div>

<div id="div-3" class="hover"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander O'Mara does a nice job of explaining why it doesn't work and shows a decent work-around.

Another work-around is to escape the plus sign by preceding it with a backslash.

```
dataI = dataI.replace('+', '\\+');
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL8gL000/)

From the [jQuery documentation for Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as
>   `` !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ `` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with
>   `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`. The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the [complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

Also note that `document.querySelector()` throws the following error when given the selector `#div-2+`:

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified.
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8rocwyq/)