# AJAX Get sending null variable to ActionResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a DropDownListFor that, when a different elementID/value is selected, should populate related elements with Model data returned from a GET ActionResult, or clear the entries from the related TextBoxFor(s) if no value is selected.  The string ID from the DropDownListFor passed to the ActionResult is always null, generating an error.  I've tried using variables for the AJAX data call, stringify-ing the data, and reading many StackOverflow questions, but the null exception still occurs.  I'm new to jQuery, so can anyone see why the data doesn't contain a value?

The View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountOwnerID, "Account Owner Name", new { @class = "req" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.AccountOwnerID, Model.AccountOwners, "--New Owner--")
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4" id="AccountOwnerName">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerName, new { @class = "req"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerName)
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="AccountOwnerPhoneNumber">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerPhoneNumber, "Owner Phone Number")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerPhoneNumber, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="AccountOwnerEmail">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerEmail, "Owner E-Mail Address")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountOwner.AccountOwnerEmail, new { @class = "form-control", data_parsley_required = "true" })
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts{

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

<script>
    $("#AccountOwnerID").change(function () {
        var $ownerName = $("#AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerName"),
            $ownerEmail = $("#AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerEmail"),
            $ownerPhone = $("#AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerPhoneNumber"),
            $ownerValue = $("#AccountOwnerID").val(),
            $aOID = { ownerID : $ownerValue };
        if (this.value >= 1) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '/Sales/GetAccountOwnerInfo',
                data: JSON.stringify($aOID),
                success: function (data) {
                    //Fill data
                    $ownerName = data.AccountOwnerName;
                    $ownerEmail = data.AccountOwnerEmail;
                    $ownerPhone = data.AccountOwnerPhoneNumber;
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            //clear fields
            $ownerName.val('');
            $ownerEmail.val('');
            $ownerPhone.val('');
        }
    }).change();
</script>
```

The Controller, which returns a model with elements to which the AJAX success assigns to the TextBoxFor(s):

```
public ActionResult GetAccountOwnerInfo(string ownerID)
    {
        Int64 accountOwnerID = 0;
        Int64.TryParse(ownerID, out accountOwnerID);

        ProjectEntities projectDB = new ProjectEntities();
        var owner = projectDB.uspGetAccountOwnerInformation(accountOwnerID).FirstOrDefault();
        AccountOwnersModel accountOwner = new AccountOwnersModel()
        {
            AccountOwnerID = owner.AccountOwnerID,
            AccountOwnerName = owner.AccountOwnerName,
            AccountOwnerEmail = owner.AccountOwnerEmail,
            AccountOwnerPhoneNumber = owner.AccountOwnerPhone,
        };

        return Json(accountOwner, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to answer with certainty, but I don't think so due to the fact that the null reference exception to the string being passed to the ActionResult, and then to the server, occurs inside the ActionResult when the DropDownListFor is toggled.

Comment: @ Script47 not all URLs must map to a file on the disk

Comment: @jle: have you tried to place a breakpoint in the action? is `ownerID` getting the correct value? also what `data` are talking about, the one in the success callback?

Comment: @Script47 I changed the URL line to "url: '/Sales/GetAccountOwnerInfo/'+$ownerValue+'.html'" and the null reference exception was still hit inside the ActionResult, but I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @StefanBaiu did not know that, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `url: '/Sales/GetAccountOwnerInfo?ownerID=' + $ownerValue`

Comment: @Stefan Baiu - I didn't place a breakpoint, but the error details direct me to the ActionResult, where I have to press Continue in order to return to the browser.  While that error detail is up, I hovered over the ownerID variable, and it had a null indicator.

Comment: also you can remove this line `data: JSON.stringify($aOID)`

Comment: @Stefan Baiu - Thanks for the URL suggestion!  The correct data now seems to be grabbed from the database, but the elements' values aren't being assigned to the TextBoxFor(s), nor are the TextBoxFor(s) clearing when a value isn't selected.  Also, no errors seem to appear in either Visual Studio or the Chrome console.

Comment: Replace `data: JSON.stringify($aOID),` with `data: $aOID,` and since its an `int`, the paramater should be `int ownerID`not `string ownerID`

Comment: And there are no elements with `$("#AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerName")` etc - look at the html your generating - its `$("#AccountOwner_AccountOwnerName")`

Comment: to update your inputs use `$ownerName.val(data.AccountOwnerName);`

Comment: Combined with the suggestions to look at the generated html, change the URL, and use .val(), this now works.  I was operating under the impression that AJAX name/value pairs were all passed as strings.  Thanks to everyone for clearing that up!  If one of you will post the URL, string-to-int, and .val(data.element) suggestions as an answer, I'd be glad to mark it as correct.

Comment: @jle glad you solved your problem, I enjoyed our little debugging session via SO comments haha, no need for points, I can't sleep right now, so I have to choose between this and thinking about my past, trust me THIS was a lot more enjoyable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `$ownerName = $("#AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerName"),` will mean `$ownerName` is undefined since you don't have any elements with `id="AccountOwner\\.AccountOwnerName"`. The html helper methods generate `id` attributes by using the replacing any `.` (and `[` and `]` characters) in the property name with `_` to avoid issues with jquery. It would need to be `$ownerName = $("#AccountOwner_AccountOwnerName")`

Secondly, you do not need to stringify the data (and if you do, then you need to specify the `contentType: 'json',` ajax option). It should be `data: { ownerID: $(this.val() },`. Note the use of `$(this)` to avoid having to search the DOM again.

Thirdly, `$ownerName` is a jquery element so to set its value, it needs to `$ownerName.val(data.AccountOwnerName);`

Side note: your usage of `if (this.value >= 1)` suggests something wrong. Your helper is generating its first option with `<option value="">--New Owner--</option>` so you should be checking for `null`.

Your script should be

```
// cache the elements since you repeatedly accessing them
var ownerName = $("#AccountOwner_AccountOwnerName"),
    ownerEmail = $("#AccountOwner_AccountOwnerEmail"),
    ownerPhone = $("#AccountOwner_AccountOwnerPhoneNumber");
$("#AccountOwnerID").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '@Url.Action("GetAccountOwnerInfo", "Sales")', // don't hard code your url's
      data: { ownerID: $(this).val() },
      success: function (data) {
        // Fill data
        ownerName.val(dataAccountOwnerName);
        ownerEmail.val(data.AccountOwnerEmail);
        ownerPhone.val(data.AccountOwnerPhoneNumber);
      }
    });
  } else {
    // clear fields
    ownerName.val('');
    ownerEmail.val('');
    ownerPhone.val('');
  }
})
```

Side note: Since your passing a value which is `int` to the method, your method parameter should be `int ownerID`. Also you don't need the value of `AccountOwnerID` in the response so you could just create an anonymous object in the controller

```
public ActionResult GetAccountOwnerInfo(int ownerID)
{
  ProjectEntities projectDB = new ProjectEntities();
  var owner = projectDB.uspGetAccountOwnerInformation(ownerID).FirstOrDefault();
  var data = new
  {
    AccountOwnerName = owner.AccountOwnerName,
    AccountOwnerName = owner.AccountOwnerName,
    AccountOwnerPhoneNumber = owner.AccountOwnerPhone
  };
  return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```