# jQuery select input element with name as array

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I Googled this for half an hour and cant find the solution but I think this should be something really simple.

This is my code

```
<input name="order[name]" id="order[name]" type="text">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#previewForm").click(function(){
            var orderName = $("input[type=text][name='order[name]']").val();
            $( "#contactCollected" ).text( orderName );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the user to preview the form that he just filled.

Replacing

```
$( "#contactCollected" ).text( orderName );
```

with

```
$( "#contactCollected" ).text( 'some text' );
```

works so I think it's the selector problem. I can provide more code if necessary.

EDIT:
It appears this works as is, I'm not even sure where in the process I replaced one mistake with another one.

Thanks For all the folks in comments especialy @Barmar and @Jonathan.Brink .

I wouldn't delete the question because of the discussion on naming ID's in input elements but I'm not sure about the rules.

Thank you everyone for your time and I apologise once more for not trying out the jsfiddle right away.

Comment: You can just use the name attr to select the input, you dont need the type as well

Comment: working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mcclaskiem/brhcga1z/

Comment: Everyone says it's not allowed, but your selector works for me in every browser and every version of JQuery I tried.

Comment: @wwwmarty I changed my answer from "not allowed" to "flaky"

Comment: @mcclaskiem I tried that too but this seemed as "more complete" selector so I did it like this.

Comment: @wwwmarty Can you be more specific on flaky, I'm pretty sure I came up to this solution on SO so I hope this is not an issue.

Comment: Flaky with regards to it not following spec. But there are a trillion differences between browsers and the spec. Might not be an issue especially since @Barmar says that this is a common PHP idiom

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/brhcga1z/1/ is your exact code, and it works fine.

Comment: @Barmar I guess I need a break here because obviously I lost my concentration. Thanks

Comment: Got it solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "type" from "text" to "input" and remove your explicit "type" declaration:

```
<input name="order[name]" id="order[name]" />

$("input[type=input][name='order[name]']")
```

Past that, a note on characters to use for dom attributes:

**For pre-HTML5 you will have flaky behavior if you use bracket's in your attributes, such as id and name.**

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You may be able to get away with the brackets with an HTML5 doctype though:

> HTML 5 is even more permissive, saying only that an id must contain at
>   least one character and may not contain any space characters.

For more details: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

I would recommend coming up with a different naming scheme for your id's, then your selectors will be more straightforward.

Multi-attribute selector example: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Comment: The form is really big and validated in the back and there is really so much to change if I change the name scheme that I really hope there is another option.
Isn't document defined as HTML 5 with `<!DOCTYPE html>` or is there something more to it. I'm self taught so it could be that I missed something big here.

Comment: @dbr which doctype are you using? Perhaps that could be changed if not HTML5?

Comment: I edited my comment above. Just a note in case you haven't seen.

Comment: @dbr ok, yep, that's the HTML5 doctype

Comment: Brackets have been used commonly in the `name` attribute for ages. It's entrenched in PHP, which automatically translates those parameters to arrays. I've never heard of it being flaky.

Comment: @Barmar If it does than that's great, but it's going against the spec (see linked SO post and http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Comment: Yes, it's against the spec, but it's been a universally-adopted extension for a long time.

Comment: PHP5 simply codified what all browsers had been doing for many years.

Comment: BTW, I'm specifically talking about the `name` attribute. The ID attribute isn't even relevant to this question, because he's not using it in the selector.

Comment: @Barmar gotcha. Probably safe then. Would try to avoid though if starting a new non-PHP project

Comment: @dbr at this point, it might be best to try to reproduce the issue in a jsfiddle

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Not just PHP, Perl also follows that naming convention (I'm not sure which did it first).

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink First time creating something in jsfiddle but this is not working. https://jsfiddle.net/4fwcfcqc/3/

Comment: @dbr You forgot to load jQuery. Select it from the menu at the top left.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click',"#previewForm",function(){
            var orderName = $("input[name='order[name]']").val();
            $( "#contactCollected" ).text( orderName );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't work even when I change `orderName` to `'some text'`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm practicing thread necromancy here so apologise in advance.  This thread is returned in searches but lacks a usable answer so I'm hoping to benefit those that follow.

The select needed for elements with square brackets as above is:
`$('#order\\[name\\]').val()`

Thanks to the following thread:
[How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Answer (score -1):

Change - `<input name="order[name]" id="order[name]" type="text">` to `<input id="order_name" type="text">` -- (square brackets are not allowed here and if specifying an I, you do not need a name - Make sure ID is unique).

Access using - `$("input#order_name").val();`

Comment: There is much more to the code than this so changing the name scheme will be the last thing I try because that will be two days of work to fix the validation and who knows what else will come up.

Comment: In that case may be you can specify a class for this input element and access using `$("input.myUniqueClass").val();`. Do not touch the existing attributes but at the same time avoid using them for your code.