# jquery $ notation returns null for document element

Tags: jquery, select, triggers, null

I am trying to use javascript to change a value of a select box on a ToysRUs address page. The project is an extension that fills out an address form automatically.

The item id is `billingAddress.address.stateSelect`

```
document.getElementById("billingAddress.address.stateSelect") // returns the element.

$("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect") // returns null.
```

I wanted to use `$("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect").val("CA")` to change the selection, but I cannot because it is null.

The page is using jQuery

```
    (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') // is true
```

I still get null after escaping the periods with backslashes.

```
s=document.getElementById("billingAddress.address.stateSelect").id;
console.log(s);
s= "#"+s.replace( /(:|\.|[|])/g, "\\$1" ); 
//also tried \\\\ backslashes and \\\ backslashes
console.log(s); //gives billingAddress\\.address\\.stateSelect
console.log($(s)); //is still null
```

Comment: In css, what would `#billingAddress.address.stateSelect` select? an element with an id of `billingAddress`, and the classnames `address` and `stateSelect`, right? jquery selectors are css selectors, and therefore certain special characters have to be escaped to select an id with said special characters.

Comment: is `#billingAddress.address.stateSelect` an `id` of your element?

Comment: relevant: [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Comment: Like @KevinB suggests, the selector may be confusing the `.` as a class: `$("#billingAddress .addres .stateSelect")` where the getElementById would not do this.

Comment: As suggested above, escape your periods. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpcxekuq/2/

Comment: Zealander -thanks for the demonstration. I will try escaping the periods.

Comment: I still get null. I'm running this in the address bar of the toysrus address page.  javascript:s=document.getElementById("billingAddress.address.stateSelect").id;alert(s);s= "#"+s.replace( /(:|\.|[|])/g, "\\$1" );alert(s);alert($(s));

Answer (score -1):

You didn't post your full code. Only things i can think of are 
1: your code runs before select loaded, this case use $(function(){your code goes here}); 
2: you can't use dots in names because browsers think it wants to tell it the dot is meaning class and not the part of the name.

Answer (score -1):

The $ notation won't necessarily work unless the jQuery has been aliased as $. Try using:

```
jQuery("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect");
```

instead of the $ sign.

Edit:

I didn't read the question carefully enough. The selector you are using is for an ID that also has two classnames, being "address" and "stateSelect". What I mentioned could still be an issue, but you need to make sure you are using the correct selectors first.