# Smooth scrolling doesn't work with a . in ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a script for smooth scrolling from here [Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717527/jquery-smooth-scrolling-when-clicking-an-anchor-link#answer-7717572) (the version where the URL is changed).

It works for all anchors except those that have a `.` in their ID.  So linking to:

- ## 1 works
- ## 1.1 doesn't work

Any idea of how to fix this?

Code:

```
var $root = $('html, body');
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://bagsy.netau.net/rj/rj.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id should not start with a digit. But if you don't want to change id, you can use this code:

```
var $root = $('html, body'); 
$('a').click(function() {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href').replace('#','');
    $root.animate({
        scrollTop: $('[id="'+href +'"]').offset().top
    }, 500, function () {
        window.location.hash = href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked.  HTML5 actually does allow IDs to start with numbers now (though HTML4 didn't).

Comment: With jQuery, to use any of the meta-characters (such as  **!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@\^{|}~**) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\ ([more](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). In your case, you can also use: `$("#2\\.1")`.