# Javascript code's dfferent behaviour

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have this piece of code

```
widgetId = "a.b";
func= function(widgetId, tableId, primaryColSearchKey)
{
    widgetId = test(widgetId);
}

    test= function(id)
    {
        id = id.replace(/\./g, "\\.").replace(/ /g, "\\ ").replace(/\(/g, "\\(").replace(/\)/g, "\\)");
        return id.replace(/\ /g, "\\ ");
    }
```

If I call it in my program it returns `a\\.b`, but if I run it w3schools website it returns `a\.b` in IE browser.

Can somebody explain why, as I want it to return `a\.b` in my code.

Comment: I see the result as `a\.b`: https://jsfiddle.net/s6ufytq5/ How are you executing this and where are you seeing `a\\.b`?

Comment: in IE browser when i call it in my local code it returns a\\.b

Comment: Show me the code. Are you outputting to the console? an alert? writing to html or an input?

Comment: That still doesn't tell me how you interrogate the value of `widgetId`. You aren't outputting it or displaying it anywhere.

Comment: i am calling a click function on it  $("#"+widgetId ).click(function(){})

Comment: So it looks like you do need two backslashes.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id

Comment: one it is working fine in chrome with one slash

Comment: Note that if you are looking at the value in IE's Developer Tools' Console or Debugger, you might see something different than looking at the same value in Chrome's Console or Source. It depends on how the tool decides to show it to you. When evaluating `a\\.b`, IE may be interpreting \\ as an escaped \ and simplifying the output for you. The real question is, as has been asked a few times here, how are you using the value? How it looks in the debugger is irrelevant.