# Why am I unable to get the value of this input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to figure out what's wrong with my code for a while now, and why it won't let me get the value of my input field.

My code looks like this:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input type=text id="0.1.2_00_1" value=0>
<script>
  console.log($('#0.1.2_00_1').val())
</script>
```

Why doesn't this work? Hopefully I'm not just being really dumb.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get jQuery to select elements with a . (period) in their ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350292/how-do-i-get-jquery-to-select-elements-with-a-period-in-their-id)

Comment: Using the old `getElementById` is one of the options: `document.getElementById('0.1.2_00_1').value`

Answer (score 4):

If an ID carries a period (special character) in jquery you must escape it like so with double slashes:

```
console.log($('#0\\.1\\.2_00_1').val());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the periods. For example `$('#0\\.1\\.2_00_1')`

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input type=text id="0.1.2_00_1" value=0>
<script>
  console.log($('#0\\.1\\.2_00_1').val())
</script>
```

As the [jQuery docs on selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) state:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` contains the `.` character which, when passed to a JQuery selector, is interpreted as a CSS class qualifier.

It's causing JQuery to look for an element who's `id` is `0` that uses a CSS class of `1` and another called `2_00_1`.

The official [spec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) says:

> "Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may
>   cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4.
>   Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start
>   with a letter for compatibility."

It's better to avoid them, if possible and use just alpha-numeric values for `id`s.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<input type=text  id="x" value=0>
<script>console.log($('#x').val())</script>
```

Comment: @Stephen You misunderstand. When `.` is used as part of a JQuery selector, it is interpreted as a CSS class identifier. The `#` is perfectly fine. See my running example.

Comment: the id is valid, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @JoeLissner The official [spec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) says: *"Using characters except ASCII letters, digits, '_', '-' and '.' may cause compatibility problems, as they weren't allowed in HTML 4. Though this restriction has been lifted in HTML 5, an ID should start with a letter for compatibility."*