# How to find a specific data attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add or remove `li`s to a list in javascript. For that purpose I found that I need to add data attributes and find the item with that value.

```
if ($('li[data-requestId=' + requestId + ']').length == 0)
{
    var element = getRequestElement();
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute("data-requestId",requestId);
    li.appendChild(element);
    $('#requestsUL').append(li);
}
```

but the first line gives this error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   li[data-requestId=6.22.20]

Comment: You need to escape the dots

Comment: what is your if fucntion aims first and how do you trigger it?

Comment: Use `if ($('li[data-requestId="' + requestId + '"]').length == 0)`

Comment: @HassanImam not enough

Comment: @HassanImam's suggestion should work; if the data attribute value is enclosed in quotes it's not necessary to escape the contents.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23340000/295783

Comment: @mplungjan oh I could guess. I have a feeling that this is not the right way to add or remove list items.. am I right?

Comment: partially yes..

Comment: It is not a recommended way I would say. Why not use jQuery all the way?
`var dataID = requestId.replace(/\./g,"_");
if ($('li[data-requestId=' + dataID + ']').length == 0)
{
    var element = getRequestElement();
    var li = $("<li/>",{"data-requestId":dataID}).append(element);
    $('#requestsUL').append(li);
}`

Comment: @mplungjan you've incorrectly marked this as a duplicate; it's not necessary to escape the dots inside the `[]` part of the selector.  `$('#x.y')` needs escaping as `$('#x\\.y')` to match `<div id="x.y">`; `$('[data-bar="x.y"]')` does *not* need escaping to match `<div data-bar="x.y">`.

Comment: @mplungjan I tested it, placing the attribute inside the quotes does the trick even if the data attribute contains dots(`.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello here is a way that let you read all the elements inside the `ul` tag based on the `data-requestId`.

I used a variable to concatenate the `li[data-requestId=""]` with the `requestId`:

```
var dataSelector='li[data-requestId="' + requestId + '"]';
```

by this way upi ensure that the selector is entirely a `string` so it will logically work. Finally here is a code snippet which demonstrate all what I've said :

```js
$(function(){

var liSize=$("ul").children().length;

for(var requestId=1;requestId<=liSize;requestId++)
{
var dataSelector='li[data-requestId="' + requestId + '"]';
console.log($(dataSelector).text());
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-requestId=1>Item 1 </li>
  <li data-requestId=2>Item 2 </li>
  <li data-requestId=3>Item 3 </li>
  <li data-requestId=4></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add extra quotes around the selector, example

```
$('li[data-requestId=a.b.c.d.e fga]');
```

will not work, but

```
$('li[data-requestId="a.b.c.d.e fga]"');
```

will work

...

change the line of code

```
if ($('li[data-requestId=' + requestId + ']').length == 0)
```

to:

```
if ($('li[data-requestId="' + requestId + '"]').length == 0)
```